# python failed to run script but successfully run line by line

Tags: python

when i run the code using Ipython3 it works.
but when I try to run it a python script via the terminal and getting the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "procces_image.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mahotas as mh

  File "/home/s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mahotas/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from . import polygon

  File "/home/s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mahotas/polygon.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _convex

ValueError: module functions cannot set METH_CLASS or METH_STATIC
```

```
import cv2
import pylab
import mahotas as mh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

path = '2_1.tif'
image = mh.imread(path)
im = Image.open(path)
img = Image.new('P', (1024, 1024))
img.paste(im)

pylab.imshow(img)
pylab.show()
print(image.shape)
im = mh.gaussian_filter(im, 4)

im = im.astype('uint8')
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im,130,255,0)
T = mh.thresholding.otsu(im)
labeled,nr_objects = mh.label(im > T)
labeled = labeled.astype('uint8')

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
pylab.imshow(im)
pylab.show()
im1 = Image.open(path)
im1.paste(im)
pylab.show()
```

the computer was recently formatted.

And all the packages are updated.

the code was originally created in Visual Studio code.

Comment: Looks like a problem with `mahotas`. Are you 100% sure it is updated?

Comment: yes, I updated pip and then reinstalled the package again

Comment: Can you try to also import numpy before importing mahotas? Just a guess

Comment: I tried, didn't work.
I 'm starting to think that the reason it doesn't work is that the code was written in python2 and i'm tring to run it on python 3

Comment: That could be it. Sorry I don't have other suggestions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the matplotlib didn't work well with the mahotas
I neened to reinstall matplotlib using 
   `sudo -H apt-get install python3-matplotlib`